# ObjectiveC waiting on for loop blocks with semaphore

Tags: ios, block, semaphore

I have to run a `method` with `block`, several times inside a `for loop`.
I also have to wait until all the `blocks` execution completes.

My problem is that I can't understand what I do wrong, that causes my entire app to freeze. Here is the code:

```
dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);//1 - creating semaphore
for(int i = 0; i< myObj.count; i++){
            [[DataManager shared] verifyObjectId:myObj[i].id
                                                     completionBlock:^(BOOL found) {
                                                         if(found){
                                                         //code here
                                                         dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);//3 - signaling semaphore to continue
                                                         }
                                                     }];
         dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);//2 -  getting semaphore to wait
}

//I want to continue once all DB checks complete
```

Now, I don't understand, why the `semaphore` won't release, and the `for loop` won't continue.

What I actually need, is for the `semaphore` to release after all the DB checks complete. Ideally, I would want the `semaphore` to wait outside the `for loop`. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

EDIT: SOLUTION: (based on the accepted answer)

```
// create a group
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
for(int i = 0; i< myObj.count; i++){
// pair a dispatch_group_enter for each dispatch_group_leave
            dispatch_group_enter(group); 
            [[DataManager shared] verifyObjectId:myObj[i].id
                                                     completionBlock:^(BOOL found) {
                                                         if(found){
                                                         //code here
                                                         }
                                                         dispatch_group_leave(group); //1 leave
                                                     }];
//Get a notification on a block that will be scheduled on the specified queue
        dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
                NSLog(@"-all done!-");
                //code here
        });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without access to `verifyObjectid:completiongBlock:`, there are a couple of issues. First, you only call `dispatch_semaphore_signal` if `found` is true. If `found` is every false, you'll deadlock. That may just be a transcription error and your real code might not do that.

Another guess is that the completion block is being submitted to the queue that you're currently running on (the main queue?) If that's true, then that would definitely be a deadlock, because you'll never run `dispatch_semaphore_signal` since it's waiting on `dispatch_semaphore_wait`. I can't tell without information about `DataManager`.

Your approach also serializes the calls, whereas I think you wanted them to be in parallel. Each call has to wait for the former one to finish in your code.

The better tools to use here are `dispatch_apply` and `dispatch_group`. Something like this (untested):

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_apply(myObj.count, dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^(size_t i){
    dispatch_group_enter(group);
    [[DataManager shared] verifyObjectId:myObj[i].id
                                                 completionBlock:^(BOOL found) {
                                                     if(found){
                                                       //code here
                                                     }
                                                     dispatch_group_leave(group));
                                                 }];
});
dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

`dispatch_apply` won't return until all the blocks have completed running, which means that `dispatch_group_enter` has run "count" times. You then use `dispatch_group_wait` to wait for all the calls to `dispatch_group_leave`.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. I'm going to experiment with what you're suggesting.